# "Not found: Table" for new bigquery table

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I use the python sdk to create a new bigquery table:

```
tableInfo = {
            'tableReference':{
                'datasetId':datasetId,
                'projectId':projectId,
                'tableId':targetTableId
            },
            'schema':schema
        }

result = bigquery_service.tables().insert(projectId=projectId,
                                          datasetId=datasetId,
                                          body=tableInfo).execute()
```

The `result` variable contains the created table information with `etag,id,kind,schema,selfLink,tableReference,type` - therefore I assume the table is created correctly.

Afterwards I even get the table, when I call `bigquery_service.tables().list(...)`

The problem is:
When inserting right after that, I still (often) get an error: `Not found: MY_TABLE_NAME`

My insert function call looks like this:

```
response = bigquery_service.tabledata().insertAll(
                        projectId=projectId,
                        datasetId=datasetId,
                        tableId=targetTableId,
                        body=body).execute()
```

I even retried the insert multiple times with 3 seconds of sleep between retries. Any ideas?

My projectId is `stylight-bi-testing`

There were a lot failures between 10:00 and 12:00 (time given in UTC)

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct table name to the insert and not a wrong constant? Can you please add to your question, the project id, and the time when the error happens, the BQ team is checking these posts, and will be able to do an internal investigation.

Comment: Hey pentium, I checked printed the 'result' variable a given above and the tableId created was the same. And actually the code works at about 50% of the time. The more retries I use the higher the chance, but I want to have a reliable way to insert data.

Comment: You are using streaming inserts or job load?

Comment: I use the streaming method (insertAll)

Comment: Is it a brand new table, or are you deleting and re-creating it?

Comment: Are you performing a streaming insert to the table before creating it? Put another way, are you using a NOT_FOUND response to a streaming insert as a signal to create the table?

Comment: @SeanChen - yes, I use the "not found" to create a new table and then try to insert again.

Comment: @JeremyCondit Yes, the table is brand new.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per your answers to my question regarding using NOT_FOUND as an indicator to create the table, this is intended (though admittedly somewhat frustrating) behavior.

The streaming insertion path caches information about tables (and the authorization of a user to insert into the table). This is because of the intended high QPS nature of the API. We also cache certain negative responses in order to protect again buggy or abusive clients. One of those cached negative responses is the non-existence of a destination table. We've always done this on a per-machine basis, but recently added an additional centralized cache, such that all machines will see the negative cache result almost immediately after the first NOT_FOUND response is returned.

In general, we recommend that table creation not occur inline with insert requests, because in a system that is issuing thousands of QPS of inserts, a table miss could result in thousands of table creation operations which can be taxing on our system. Instead, if you know the possible set of tables beforehand, we recommend some periodic process that performs table creations in advance of their usage as a streaming destination. If your destination tables are more dynamic in nature, you may need to implement a delay after table creation has been performed.

Apologies for the difficulty. We do hope to address this issue, but we don't have any timeframe yet for doing so.

Comment: Note... if you create the table before attempting to stream to the destination, the table is available immediately.